# Passing count variable in setInterval function

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I am attempting to step through the array and every 3 seconds change the innerHTML of some items in the DOM. This code currently goes straight from 0(mixed media artist) to 2(descriptor) and doesn't display 1(art educator) at all. And the console.log outputs 0 1 2 for each setinterval loop.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong to get this to work properly?

```
var heroItems = ['galleries', 'workshops', 'exhibitions'];
var heroBtns = ['view', 'sign UP', 'VIEW'];
var heroURLs = ['#', '#', '#'];
var descriptions = ['mixed media artist', 'art educator', 'descriptor'];

setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++){
      console.log(i)
      changeDescription(i);
    }
}, 3000);


function changeDescription(i) {
    var descriptor = document.getElementById('descriptor').innerHTML = descriptions[i];
    var hero = document.getElementById('hero').innerHTML = heroItems[i];
    var heroRef = document.getElementById('heroref').setAttribute('href', heroURLs[i]);
    var heroBtn = document.getElementById('herobtn').innerHTML = heroBtns[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you don't wait after each loop iteration. You only wait once, after changing the description 3 times.

In your case, you could also totally skip the loop.

```
var i = 0;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    changeDescription(i);
    if (++i == descriptions.length) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 3000);
```